# Sail.js - how to structure JSON based live data output with existing static data in the model

Tags: node.js, sails.js

In my Angular app, I want to display a table which contains the following
a) URL
b) Social share counts divided by different social networks

Using Sails.js, I already have the api created for the URL when the results show up, I can display the URL now I'm confused how to get the appropriate social counts showing right besides

Here's the API I'm using: https://docs.sharedcount.com/
by itself, I can see the JSON it produces

But here are my questions:

1. Should I create a new api (model/controller) for social count data or include it in my model where I have the 'url' action defined?
2. If I create a new api or include the social_counts as an action in the current, what would my JSON query look like? to retrieve the URL's, I'm using default API blueprint that Sails provides, so:

   `http://www.example.com/url/find?where={"title":{"contains":"mark"}}`

Struggling a bit in terms of the thought process, would be great to get input on this

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on your app. is your app will store that data or just consume it? If it need to store, of course you need the API. In purpose for modification or aggregating the data for example.
2. No, you can't do that. That shortcut method only works if you have the data in your database and let the Sails Waterline ORM and Blueprint API served it.

Perhaps, if you only need to consume the data from that Sharedcount API, you didn't need to use Sails as a backend, in this context. Just use Angular as a client of that API. Except if you need to modify the data first and store it in your own database, so Sails will helps with it's Waterline ORM and Blueprint API.

Comment: Thanks Andy! don't want to store that data per se since the values keep changing. If I mention that API key in the Angular app, everyone else would also be able to see it, right? (which means it would be insecure) - if so, then what would the best approach be to not have that data stored in the DB but at the same time, make it such that the clients can't see it

Comment: I see, you want to "protect" your request? If so, you just need a controller, not a whole API (in Sails point of view). Try `$ sails generate controller someController`, then you will get a controller.

After that use that controller to make a request. You can use `request` module from `NPM`.